# IOS Facebook singleton and get profile picture

Tags: ios, facebook, singleton

I am trying to get a profile picture from a UIViewController.

My Facebook is in a singleton class.
From UIViewController
[[myfacebook shared requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];
this doesn't work if i need to login or app fire the first time.
because authorize was being called and didlogin being called.

This line was not hit.
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

How do i go around with these scenario
1.Singleton Facebook instance class,
2.calling from UIViewController 
3. need login.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a protocol called FacebookSingletonDelegate

```
@class FacebookSingleton; 

@protocol FacebookSingletonDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) facebookSingletonDidLogin:(FacebookSingleton *) facebookSingleton;

- (void) facebookSingletonDidNotLogin:(FacebookSingleton *) facebookSingleton;

- (void) facebookSingletonDidLogout:(FacebookSingleton *) facebookSingleton;

- (void) facebookSingleton:(FacebookSingleton *)facebookSingleton
            request:(FBRequest *) request
            didLoad:(id)result;


@end
```

Then create a property in your FacebookSingleton.h like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<FacebookSingletonDelegate> delegate;
```

Then have your view controller conform to the protocol -

```
@interface MyViewController<FacebookSingletonDelegate>
```

Then, set yourself as the delegate in your view controller, Ex -

```
myViewController.delegate = self;
```

Then, trigger the delegate method from the FacebookSingleton implementation (FacebookSingleton.m) -

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{
  [self.delegate facebookSingleton:self request:request didLoad:result]; 
}
```

Then, you can just implement the following method inside your view controller -

```
- (void) facebookSingleton:(FacebookSingleton *)facebookSingleton
            request:(FBRequest *) request
            didLoad:(id)result
{
 // the view controller will receive the event in here
}
```